# Asynchbase throwing lots of zookeeper timeouts when doing many inserts. Eventually it runs out of memory. Why?

Tags: hbase

I'm trying to test the performance of Asynchbase by running a simple "Insert some random data as fast as you can" test. The code for the test is roughly this:

```
org.hbase.async.HBaseClient client = new org.hbase.async.HBaseClient(zookeeperServer);
client.setFlushInterval((short)250);
Random rand = new Random();
long stoptime, elapsedTime;
double elapsedSeconds;
int counter = 0;
long absolutestart = System.nanoTime();
long starttime = absolutestart;

for (int xx = 1; xx <= numberOfRows; xx++) {
    byte[] rowKey = new byte[20];
    rand.nextBytes(rowKey);
    byte[] data = new byte[50];
    rand.nextBytes(data);
    counter += 1;
    PutRequest put = new PutRequest(Runner.TABLENAME.getBytes(), rowKey, "data".getBytes(), "col".getBytes(), data);
    client.put(put);

    //Flush the puts if we've hit the batchsize
    if (xx % batchSize == 0) {
        client.flush();
        stoptime = System.nanoTime();
        elapsedTime = (stoptime - starttime);
        elapsedSeconds = (double) elapsedTime / 1000000000.0;
        System.out.println(String.format("%d completed in %.6f s, %d ns, %.6f /s", counter, elapsedSeconds, elapsedTime, (batchSize / elapsedSeconds)));
        counter = 0;
        starttime = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
client.shutdown();
stoptime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(String.format("%d inserts in in %.6f s, %d ns, %.6f msg/s", numberOfRows, ((double) (stoptime - absolutestart)) / 1000000000.0, (stoptime - absolutestart), (numberOfRows / (((double) (stoptime - absolutestart)) / 1000000000.0))));
```

I have a similar codebase for testing both the default HBase and the Thrift APIs. Those tests work great, but for the Asynchbase code runs into issues with zookeeper sessions timing out. Eventually, the inserts stop, and it throws an `OutOfMemoryError`. I'm setting the number of rows to insert to be 10m, and the batchsize to be 10k.

```
10000 completed in 0.006476 s, 6476111 ns, 1544136.596794 /s
14/06/10 12:02:09 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 3729ms for sessionid 0x34656836aec21e8, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
10000 completed in 2.850325 s, 2850325467 ns, 3508.371278 /s
10000 completed in 0.006344 s, 6343748 ns, 1576355.176782 /s
10000 completed in 0.006112 s, 6111646 ns, 1636220.422452 /s
10000 completed in 0.006011 s, 6010528 ns, 1663747.344659 /s
10000 completed in 0.006280 s, 6280169 ns, 1592313.837414 /s
14/06/10 12:02:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x34656836aec21e8 closed
14/06/10 12:02:10 WARN async.HBaseClient: No longer connected to ZooKeeper, event=WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null
14/06/10 12:02:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=trth-hadoop01,trth-hadoop02,trth-hadoop03 sessionTimeout=5000 watcher=org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$ZKClient@220b1039
14/06/10 12:02:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server zookeeperhost3/10.52.136.91:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
14/06/10 12:02:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
14/06/10 12:02:11 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to zookeeperhost3/10.52.136.91:2181, initiating session
10000 completed in 0.972888 s, 972887644 ns, 10278.679210 /s
14/06/10 12:02:11 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server zookeeperhost3/10.52.136.91:2181, sessionid = 0x34656836aec21e9, negotiated timeout = 5000
14/06/10 12:02:11 INFO async.HBaseClient: Connecting to .META. region @ 10.52.136.101:60020
14/06/10 12:02:11 ERROR zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Caught unexpected throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hbase.async.RegionClient
        at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$RegionClientPipeline.init(HBaseClient.java:2630)
        at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient.newClient(HBaseClient.java:2579)
        at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient.access$2700(HBaseClient.java:179)
        at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$ZKClient$ZKCallback.handleMetaZnode(HBaseClient.java:3276)
        at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$ZKClient$ZKCallback.processResult(HBaseClient.java:3132)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:561)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)
10000 completed in 0.007104 s, 7103562 ns, 1407744.452713 /s
10000 completed in 0.006117 s, 6117418 ns, 1634676.590679 /s
[... more inserts ...]
10000 completed in 2.284842 s, 2284841896 ns, 4376.670446 /s
10000 completed in 2.300403 s, 2300402665 ns, 4347.065039 /s
14/06/10 12:02:31 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 4931ms for sessionid 0x34656836aec21e9, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
14/06/10 12:02:39 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server zookeeperhost2/10.52.136.90:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
14/06/10 12:02:55 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to zookeeperhost2/10.52.136.90:2181, initiating session
14/06/10 12:03:13 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x34656836aec21e9 closed
14/06/10 12:03:16 WARN async.HBaseClient: No longer connected to ZooKeeper, event=WatchedEvent state:Disconnected type:None path:null
14/06/10 12:03:18 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeperhost1,zookeeperhost2,zookeeperhost3 sessionTimeout=5000 watcher=org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$ZKClient@220b1039
14/06/10 12:03:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
14/06/10 12:04:00 WARN util.ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '' failed, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:108)
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:236)
        at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents(FileUtil.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDelete(FileUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents(FileUtil.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDelete(FileUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents(FileUtil.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDelete(FileUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents(FileUtil.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDelete(FileUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents(FileUtil.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDelete(FileUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents(FileUtil.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDelete(FileUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.fullyDelete(FileUtil.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar$1.run(RunJar.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
```

What's going on here? Have I made a bad assumption somewhere in the codebase - is asynchbase not suitable for this type of usage pattern? Or is there a bug/error somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this, literally within about 10 minutes of posting the bounty.

The problem was with how I was calling the application. I'm running a whole bunch of tests, some mapreduce, some pure hbase and was running the jar like this:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hbase classpath` HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop/ yarn jar myjar.jar
```

Obviously, for a pure hbase test, you don't need the MAPRED_HOME, or to run it via yarn. If I run it simply using

```
java -cp `hbase classpath` -jar myjar.jar
```

I don't get any of the problems.